# How do I lookup Industry by Symbol on Yahoo using ruby?

Tags: ruby, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am trying to get company information for a given symbol, and I have gotten quotes data using a wonderful 'yahoo-finance' gem, but now I need to get company's industry information, and can't find a way.

Any ideas?

Comment: `yahoo-finance` gem does not supply this information. It is an extremely simple wrapper that pulls data from Yahoo Finance API as a CSV and then parses it for you. This data does not contain any information regarding the industry. There is a gem in development [`yahoo_finance`](https://github.com/takismercouris/yahoo_finance) That uses nokgiri for page scraping and does seem to support this but it does not appear to be production ready by it's own admission.

Comment: Thanks, @engineersmnky.  In reality, I'd be more than happy to simply understand how to get this data from YQL query (if possible).  I don't really care for a gem at this stage.  :)

Comment: In that case you could do the page scraping yourself. the endpoint would be "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=[symbol]" e.g. [Google Profile Page](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=GOOG). Chekcout nokogiri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `:industry` to the list of fields you want returned.  `available_fields` gives you the full list.  E.g.,

```
require 'yahoo_finance'
stocks = YahooFinance::Stock.new(['AAPL'], [:industry, :sector])
# use stocks.available_fields to search for the fields that you want
results = stocks.fetch; nil
results['AAPL'][:industry]
# "Electronic Equipment"
results['AAPL'][:sector]
# "Consumer Goods"
```